# Why can FileOutputStream's write() method write a character but OutputStreamWriter's cannot?

Tags: java

(1)

```
OutputStreamWriter ows = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("A.txt"));
ows.write('a');
```

(2)

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("B.txt");
fos.write('a');
```

(2) can successfully write 'a', but (1) cannot. Who can tell me why?

Comment: ...because the architects of Java designed to be this way.  `OutputStreamWriter` takes a `FileOutputStream` in its constructor.  So if you want to write a single character to an `OSW`, you certainly can do so, via the `FOS` which you created in your code snippet above.

Comment: @daniu What was wrong on your answer?

Comment: In B.txt file, can show 'a', but A.txt cannot. But the argument is same@ Tim Biegelesen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both can write a byte/char to a file (in the case of `OutputStream` you're actually writing a `byte`, and with `Writer` a `char`).

Your particular issue is that you don't **`close()`** the output stream, which you should always do in order for the data to be flushed to disk.

A `Writer` has a small buffer. You can force a flush by calling [`flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush()) or just closing it.

```
OutputStreamWriter ows = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("a.txt"));
ows.write('a');
ows.close();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("b.txt");
fos.write('b');
fos.close();
```

Or better yet:

```
try (OutputStreamWriter ows = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("a.txt"))) {
    ows.write('a');
}
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("b.txt")) {
    fos.write('b');
}
```